# Change iPhone Grouped TableView's Width

Tags: iphone

I wonder if it's possible to adjust the width of a grouped tableview.
I want to have a wider table.
Is this possible? and how?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be blunt Mike but you're wrong.  The table's width is not already set to the maximum. creator7 hit the nail on the head, you can resize tables, including grouped tables, in Interface Builder. If you need it larger than the screen (can't imagine why you would want this...), you might need to do further sizing programmatically.  If the table has been added in IB, then best to do this programmatic resizing in the viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method.

Answer (score 0):

The width on tables is already set to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

you have to increase the width of the table using interface builder manually for scroll upto its width add the tableview as subview of a scrollview.